# How to show active block and menu of admin template gentelella in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, templates, menu

Hi I used admin template gentelella in codeigniter
I want to show selected menu as active and block open based on url.
In my project each link has different controller in list pages to add for other modules which[image] is not in menu list.

my code is like

```
<li><a><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Master <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav child_menu">
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/A">A List</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/B">B Contacts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/C">C List</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/D">D Products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/E">E Limit</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/F">F content</a></li>    

                    </ul>   
                  </li>
```

In A list page I have another link to add child documents, this controller is not in this menu list.

Comment: Your question wasn't clear

Answer (score 0):

While I am not 100% familiar with the template you mention, I have done similar within CodeIgniter apps (using Bootstrap) by checking the uri segment.  Maybe try something like this:

```
<li<?php if( $this->uri->segment(1) == 'admin') && $this->uri->segment(2) == 'A') echo ' class="active"'; ?>>
    <a href="<?php echo site_url("admin/A"); ?>"> A List</a>
</li>
```

Hopefully this helps, or at least points you in the right direction.